# Django Queryset only

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am wanting to select only a few fields in a query set of a model. I saw this link: [Django queryset only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) and I thought I implement it, but I am still getting the entire query set.

This is my Project view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Project

# Create your views here.
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Project.objects.only("name","jobNumber", "contractor", "assigned_to", "created_date")
    template_name = 'project/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        #return Project.objects.all()
        return Project.objects.only("name","jobNumber", "contractor", "assigned_to", "created_date")

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project/detail.html'
```

This is my index.html template

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Projects</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for project in project_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'project:detail' project.id %}">{{ project.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}

    </ul>
    {% render_table project_list %}
{% endblock %}
```

The above code gives me all the fields in the Project model. How do I select only a few of the fields in Projects?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) specifies which fields should be populated from the database, but it does not prevent other fields on the model from being accessed. If you want to limit the fields available in the resultant objects then you should use [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values) or [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) instead. Note that neither of them returns models, since using a model would still make the other fields available.